# Issue with jQuery bxslider: ALL images are visible when sliding/animating on Firefox Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

I'm using jquery with bxslider to create a very simple slider, and it works fine on desktop, but when I view it on Firefox Mobile (Android), I'm able to see all the images as they are being animated and scrolling (when, obviously, I only want to see one image).

The code is simple:

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="bxslider">
        <li><a href=""><img src="./images/1.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><img src="./images/2.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><img src="./images/3.jpg" /></a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

The `.left`, `.right` divs are arrows (controls) for the slider.

The widths of the slider and the images are correct.

All three elements (slider and controls) are floated left and contained within a container which has `margin: 0 auto` to center it.

Nothing else unusual is going on, but it's driving me crazy.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine when there are only a few sliders on the page; I gather that this is just a rendering issue with bxSlider having too many sliders on the same page and not much can be done to avoid it.